# Terminology for primary decomposition of finite abelian group

Tags: group-theory, terminology, abelian-groups

I have a finite abelian group $G$ which I've decomposed in primary form as
$$ G = \mathbb Z / r_1 \times \dots \times \mathbb Z / r_n $$
where $r_1 \mid \dots \mid r_n$. Questions:

1. Is there a name for the number $n$ above? (In other words, the maximal $\mathbb Z$-independent set.)
2. Is there a name for the number $r_n$ above? (In other words, the maximal order in the group.)

Apologies if these are obvious. I spent a while searching Google and haven't found anything, but I think I'm not using the right search keywords.

Comment: The number $r_n$ is called the *exponent* of the group.  I don't know any name for $n$, but someone else might.